# Is Schrieffer-Wolff transformation equivalent to Feynman diagram and Path integral?

Tags: condensed-matter, path-integral, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action, hamiltonian

In high energy community, people usually use path integral (or Feynman diagram) to derive effective action (or effective Hamiltonian). However, in condensed matter or AMO community, people usually use Schrieffer-Wolff transformation to derive it. I am curious about whether path integral, Feynman diagram, and Schrieffer-Wolff transformation are equivalent. The only reference that I can find is [The Functional Integral formulation of the Schrieffer-Wolff transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02373). In this article, they only demonstrate the equivalence by giving an example. I am wondering if they are equivalent in general. Maybe there is some subtlety.

To be honest, Feynman diagram is more intuitive for me than Schrieffer-Wolff transformation. If I can know that they are equivalent, then I can just use Feynman rules to get the effective action.
Thanks!